# Kafka Consumer Offset -1

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have a set of Kafka Partitions.In a specific Kafka partition , I see more than 4K messages & I see the consumer offset as -1. What does -1 mean?

Comment: Where do you see the value -1 for offset?

Comment: I see it in Kafka monitor